# Setting div height to equal width ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm aware this is a popular question. I've read solutions to this including setting padding-bottom to equal width. As well as assigning this to the pseudo element so it's easier to insert content. (Plus other css solutions).
[css height same as width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width)

These do work but it's giving me trouble with some of the content I insert and it's not worth the hassle (since my whole site is construction from these squares).

I'm a novice when it comes to javascript but would there be an easy solution to enable a divs height to equal width. ( Sorry I'm too novice to even show an attempt :/ )

I try not to ask too many "write code for me" questions so references or explanations would be equally appreciated.

***Answer:*** **Thanks Jacob** just to add onto your code this now works on resize incase anyone else has this same problem https://jsfiddle.net/pekqh5z1/4/

```
function updateSize(){
var box = $(".test");
box.css("height", box.width());
}

$( window ).resize(updateSize);
$(document).ready(function(){
updateSize();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super easy to do.

To edit set the style of an element with JS, you set the desired property of the `style` method.

```js
var test = document.querySelector(".test");
test.style.height = getComputedStyle(test).width;
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Super uber goober</div>
```

With the JS, we first select the first appearance of `.test`, and assign it to a variable(`var test = document.querySelector(".test");`)

We then get the computed width of the element, and set that as its height(`test.style.height = getComputedStyle(test).width;`)

For the sake of completeness, here's a jQuery solution as well:

```js
var test = $(".test");
test.css("height", test.width());
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Super uber goober</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Not to sound ungrateful but I'm having trouble with resizing. It seems to load fine but as you resize the window the height stays the same as the width continues to change. https://jsfiddle.net/pekqh5z1/

Comment: @MaxPower add your code into resize event so height will change aswell as you resize the window.

Comment: @JF-Mechs Thanks for the tip :) ... now the height only loads as I resize the window and not on the initial load haha...so close. I'll try and fix it myself but if you know the solution I won't stop you. https://jsfiddle.net/pekqh5z1/1/

Comment: @MaxPower https://jsfiddle.net/r2dpqv3f/ just wrap it in a function and call it on page load

Comment: @JacobGray Thanks for the help. I managed to come up with the similar solution on the resizing/loading issue (bottom of original post).

Comment: @MaxPower **add your code into resize event** :) that means you should not remove the code for initial load .. you're code should look like these..
 
`var test = document.querySelector(".test");
test.style.height = getComputedStyle(test).width;
window.onresize = function(event) {
   test.style.height = getComputedStyle(test).width;
};`
but I think you should use Jacob solution :)

Comment: @JF-Mechs Both mine and Jacobs solutions load the div with an additional 17px height for some reason, it fixes on resizes however. You're solution doesn't have the additional 17px height on load, I got it working in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pekqh5z1/3/ ...When I put it in my project it gives me a height of 0px...Damn I hate jquery haha.

Comment: @MaxPower I would recommend not using jQuery, at least when you are new to JS. Anything you can do with jQuery, you can also do with plain JS

Comment: @JacobGray You're probably right, but for now I'll stick with this jQuery as I've almost got it. I now see why it's loading at a height 17px too high, because the scroll bar is 17px wide which is giving a false reading. Not sure why it fixes once I resize the window though -.-